# How to add and remove a select box with options?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a user page that displays select option like e.g city name abc, and city name bcd. I want to dynamically add and remove cities from admin page to user page. I am new to java script and HTML.

On user page:

```
<script src="add.js"></script>
<form>
     <select id="newCity">
        <option>city1</option>
        <option>city2</option>
        <option>city3</option>
        <option>city4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Admin page:

```
<script src="add.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="newCity">
        <option>city1</option>
        <option>city2</option>
        <option>city3</option>
        <option>city4</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert city</button>
```

add.js file:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("newCity");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "new city";
    x.add(option);
}
```

Comment: add some code , did you tried something?

Comment: code added bellow.

Comment: Please edit your code into your question instead of posting it as an answer, unless it actually answers your question.

Comment: i am new here didn't know about that thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a place from where both pages can retrieve data

I will use array

**You need to call one() on user page load so that option values update immediately**

I've added another button

```
 <button type="button" onclick="one()">Insert</button>
```

And then in javascript I've added array for holding values

```
 myarray = ["city1","city2","city3","city4","yo"];
```

myfunction()

```
...
var x = document.getElementById("newCity");
var option = document.createElement("option");

value="new";
option.text = value;
myarray.push(value);
x.add(option);
...
```

one()

```
...
var x = document.getElementById("newCity");
x.innerHTML= "";
for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");

    value=myarray[i];
    option.text = value;
    x.add(option);
}
...
```

Comment: i am trying to add new values in select option which is displayed on user page. i am trying to add these new values from another page like admin

Comment: @Writer Is this what you're looking for